# conditional search across multiple columns in very large dataframe, goal to create 1/0 column for other analysis using R

Tags: r

hi sorry if this seems super straightforward but i'm having trouble figuring out how to get R to look across multiple columns using a grepl(^x, ^y, ^z) or %in% c(x, y, z) and when true or match, creating a new 1/0 column at end of dataframe. i've tried lots of variations but seem only to be able to filter down to a smaller dataframe then add 1s, but then i lose the original dataframe. or, use many nested ifelse to mutate a 1/0 column in the original dataframe, but this feels sloppy and likely to lead to mistakes.

any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you do add a small example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @gered It would be much easier to understand your need and to provide a possible solution if you could provide an example or a sample of the data and the codes you tried so far.

Comment: right! something like this, taking a very large dataframe and looking at multiple columns, in this case, R_1 through R_20. here's a smaller sample of the ifelse code that works well but gets very LONG!       c95 <- c95 %>% mutate(Opioid_Specific = ifelse(grepl('^96500|^96501|^96502|^96509', R_1), 1,
                                        ifelse(grepl('^96500|^96501|^96502|^96509', R_2), 1,
                                        ifelse(grepl('^96500|^96501|^96502|^96509', R_3), 1, 
                                        ifelse(grepl('^96500|^96501|^96502|^96509', R_4), 1, 0))))

Comment: what i'd like to achieve is a data frame with new columns that have 1s where certain conditions match across multiple other columns, such as !grepl("567|568") & grepl("569"). what i cant figure out is how to get grepl to look through many columns within an ifelse.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the `across` function, e.g. to look through the first 3 columns of a data.frame using certain searchPattern you can do:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% mutate(Opioid_Specific= sum(across(1:3, ~as.numeric(grepl(searchPattern, .))))) %>% 
  mutate(Opioid_Specific= ifelse(Opioid_Specific>= 1,1,0 ))
```

Another option would be to use the output of a normal (combined) condition as numeric, e.g.:

```
data %>% mutate(Opioid_Specific= as.numeric(grepl(searchPattern, R1) | grepl(searchPattern, R2) | grepl(searchPattern, R3)))
```